# Get the list of DOI value from JSON URL

Tags: php, json, parsing, doi

I have a short JSON file from URL

`https://api.crossref.org/works?query.title=Tuberculosis+drug&filter=type:journal-article,from-print-pub-date:2010,until-print-pub-date:2010&select=DOI&rows=3`

I used this code to get `total-results` and the list of `DOI` value

```
$crossref_api_url = 'https://api.crossref.org/works?query.title=Tuberculosis+drug&filter=type:journal-article,from-print-pub-date:2010,until-print-pub-date:2010&select=DOI&rows=2';

$JSON = file_get_contents($crossref_api_url);
$Array = json_decode($JSON, true);          

$items_list = $message->items; 
$totalItems = $message->total-results;  
echo $totalItems;

for($i = 0; $i < count($items_list ); $i++) {
    $doi = $items_list[$i]->items->DOI;
    echo $doi;  
}
```

The result appears `0`. There are no `totalItems` value, `DOI` list.

Please help me the find the mistake of my code. Thank you

Comment: `$message`?  Where is it __defined__?

Comment: And the structure you got is `{ "message": { "items": [{ "DOI": "10.1111\/j.1365-2958.2010.07218.x"}`, but you are trying to access message->items->items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct code:

```
$crossref_api_url = 'https://api.crossref.org/works?query.title=Tuberculosis+drug&filter=type:journal-article,from-print-pub-date:2010,until-print-pub-date:2010&select=DOI&rows=2';

$JSON = file_get_contents($crossref_api_url);
$Array = json_decode($JSON, true);          // with `true` you decode to ARRAY

$items_list = $Array['message']['items']; 
$totalItems = $Array['message']['total-results'];  
echo $totalItems;

foreach ($items_list as $item) {
    echo $item['DOI'];  
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works well but the `$totalItems` doesn't show.

Comment: It does, check your code __again__. Or check __output__ of your code. To add a newline `echo PHP_EOL;`